# Installing deduplication plugin on RabbitMQ hosted in Amazon MQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amazon-mq

How to install RabbitMQ deduplication plugin (https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) on RabbitMQ hosted in Amazon MQ?